# Russia visa application: no surname to fill in

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, russia

I am currently applying for a Russian visa. My Indian passport has only the first name (all my names are together in the first name section), it doesn't have a surname. As I understand, for US visas, one usually fills "FNU" in this case. Can someone please tell me what should be filled in the Russian visa application?

Comment: Is the field mandatory?

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory.

Comment: How many names do you have?

Comment: My name follows the pattern name.A.B where A and B are my initials. In my passport, the first-name field has all these together, with full forms of my initials too.

Comment: You can split your name into first and last for the visa. When visa arrives it will matches with passport name. All they care for is a match. except for spelling mistakes. Immigration understands the first and surnames are different based on every countries etc..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The instruction from the Russian consulate is to use '-' (hyphen) in the surname field. Got it as a reply to the mail concerning this query.